# Canvas - Clear rect is not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I want to move a rect from the top to the bottom of the canvas. But somehow the canvas does not get cleared. What is wrong?

[js fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/job6uy42/1/)

JS

```
(function animloop(){
  requestAnimFrame(animloop);
  redraw();
})();


    function redraw() {

        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth, canvasHeight);
        ctx.rect(20,y,50,50);
        ctx.fillStyle="red";
        ctx.fill(); 
        y += 2;

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is cleared, but you do not start new path, thus the old keeps being re-painted.

Add:

```
ctx.beginPath();
```

in the `redraw()` function.

You might also want to look at

- [What exactly is a canvas path, and what is the use of ctx.closePath()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10807230/3278057)
- [Canvas consumes a lot of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7658523/3278057)

and/or similar.